# Getting the value at the intersection of a row and column in a pytorch tensor matrix

Tags: python, pytorch

I am new to pytorch and am looking to get a value at an index from a matrix. There is a matrix called `psfm_s` that has been initialized with 
`psfm_s=Var(torch.randn(12,20),requires_grad=True)` For example, I would like to to get the number in the first column (out of 12 columns)  and the number in the first row (out of 20 rows).

I have tried doing something like `index=torch.tensor([0,0])`
`num_at_index=psfm_s[index]` to get the desired number but that just gets me a tensor with a bunch of numbers in it, I'm not really sure what happens with this method.

I just want the one number at the desired index, how can I go about doing this if it's even possible? Thanks for the help!

Comment: `psfm_s[index]` gives you a row of the tensor. Instead you can just directly index the row and column of the matrix `num_at_index=psfm_s[0,0].item()` where item converts a single element tensor to a number.

Comment: @jodag Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reproduce the described code in its completeness (for future reference, please provide a [mcve] in your question), and taking the already correct solution from @jodag in the comments, consider this code snippet:

```
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch

psfm_s = Variable(torch.randn(12,20), requires_grad=True)
single_value = psfm_s[0,0].item()
print(single_value) # prints a single random number from your tensor
```

For some background information, consider [the official docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.item):

> Returns the value of this tensor as a standard Python number. This
>   only works for tensors with one element. For other cases, see `tolist()`.
>
> This operation is not differentiable.

Consequently, getting a complete row (or column), would look like this:

```
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch

psfm_s = Variable(torch.randn(12,20), requires_grad=True)
single_row_tensor = psfm_s[0,:]
single_row_list = single_row_tensor.tolist()
single_row_numpy_1 = single_row_tensor.data.numpy()
single_row_numpy_2 = single_row_tensor.detach().numpy()

# the following doesn't work, as it is a torch.Variable with gradient history:
single_row_fail = single_row_tensor.numpy()
```

In the case you want to get a NumPy array, you have to be careful not to directly cast it to `.numpy()`, as this causes issues with the gradient history of the Variable. You can either use `.data.numpy()`, or `.detach().numpy()`. 
There seems to be [some discussion](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/help-clarifying-repackage-hidden-in-word-language-model/226/2) as to which one is preferred, but both should work for your case.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the detail!